# AWS EC2 t2.micro boxes sending 503 error

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a service running on t2.micro boxes configured via ElasticBeanStalk. The number of requests coming on each box is roughly 100ps and average response time is under 100ms.

During high traffic the some of the http requests are failing with 503 error.

[image: 503 Error on service call]

There are lot of such spikes while monitoring the service in cloudwatch. The traffic is dropped from the boxes because the errors are listed under HTTP 5xxs and not ELB 5xxs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html). This led me to testing the access logs on the box. On checking the httpd access logs I see a lot of 503 errors but there is not a single 503 error in the tomcat's access log.

Is there a way in which I can fix this?

Comment: What do the CPU credits on those servers look like when this is happening?

Comment: seems errors are at Web server end. Can you check if static files(css, js, images) loaded by httpd servers are rendered properly including the files loaded from cdn?

Comment: This generally means that the Tomcat did not respond to Apache quickly enough. The timeout is probably 30-60 seconds. You are probably over capacity for micro instances. They do drop significantly in available CPU resources once they run out credits.

Comment: @harshavmb I do not have any static files for the service that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

All t2 instances are considered burstable. They use a credit model. While idle, they build credits (up to cap) while active they use credits.

Once they reach 0, they are throttled to a very low amount of CPU resources.

This error is generated by apache as it times out waiting for Tomcat. Likely due to the above reason. You can check your instance credit levels to confirm this.

Comment: Avg credit balance is more than 50 on these boxes all the time. So I am not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: Earlier I had just monitored over the last half an hour. On looking deeper for multiple days for some limited period of time my minimum credit balance is going to zero and hence this can be an issue.